# Detect when a graph has been broken into two or more connected components

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

I have a computer science problem that I've been thinking a lot about lately, and I'd be interested to hear other people's feedback:

Let's say you have a 3d blockworld (like minecraft).  The world is "stable" if, for any block, there exists a solid path from that block to the bottom-most row of blocks.  When the world is generated, it's guaranteed to be stable, but as players go around digging up the blocks, they could make the world unstable.  For example, the player could dig out the trunk of a tree, in which case the top of the tree would be hovering in midair, and thus the world is unstable.

The goal is to quickly figure out if the world becomes unstable as the result of a dig, and which cubes should be removed to restore the world to a stable state.  The algorithm should be fast and work in the context of a world where many digs are taking place, most of which do not make the world unstable.

One naive approach would be to take each adjacent cube after a dig and find a path to the bottom of the earth.  If you can't find a path to the bottom from any of the neighbors, the world is now unstable (and you also learn which cubes to remove as part of the process).  This falls apart when the path to the bottom is very long.  It's pretty easy to come up with an example where this becomes computationally expensive (Imagine removing the top of a large, winding tower).

This problem can be thought of as a graph problem where you want to quickly detect if a single vertex can divide the graph into two or more components.

I'm interested to hear if anyone has other ideas of ways to make this problem tractable.

Comment: what about the case where I dig out a block under a tree but the tree continues to be held up, pinned to a block on one or both sides? also how do you differentiate between building a bridge and causing instability? and what about flying trees vs the normal ones?

Comment: +1 I never imagined that Minecraft could lead to something interesting!

Comment: @groovy I'm not considering instability.  If there is a path to the bottom-most layer of cubes, then the structure is supported, regardless of the laws of physics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Link/cut tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link/cut_tree) may help you.  [Daniel Sleator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniel_Sleator), on of the authors of that structure [shared his solution](http://codeforces.com/contest/117/submission/860934) to the [similar problem](http://codeforces.ru/contest/117/problem/E?locale=en). Look [his comments on codeforces.ru](http://codeforces.ru/blog/entry/2752#comment-63273) you may find them useful.

I would write here my idea. Let's create one vertex under the bottom level. This vertex is the basement of your building. Connect basement_vertex with all vertices at the bottom level. Run depth first search (DFS) from basement vertex. This dfs will produce rooted tree. This tree should be base (initial stage) of some link-cut tree.

**UPDATE**

Link-Cut Trees works only when given graph is a tree. For **any** graph we have to solve  **dynamic connectivity problem.** [Here](http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.851/spring12/scribe/L20.pdf)  more info about dynamic connectivity problem.

Comment: So, to summarize what you are saying: Create a spanning tree starting from a node at the bottom, then if a node is removed from the tree such that it splits the tree into one or more subtrees, try to link the subtrees?  I think this is on the right track, let me see how to link the trees...

Comment: Oh, I forgot that your graph is not necessary a tree) Link-Cut Trees suits only when given graph is a tree.  Your problem is deeper and it's called dynamic connectivity problem. In particular, your case is `Decremental -  Supports only deletions of vertices and edges`. Read [this](http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.851/spring12/scribe/L20.pdf) to get more info about dynamic connectivity problem.

Comment: It turns out the solution for regular graphs is to create a spanning tree and then, after a delete, to merge trees together based on the unused edges.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider storing if each block is "unstable-if-dug", also known as a *cut-vertex* or *biconnected component*. Then you can look it up in constant time when clicked.

Basically, the idea is to be able to immediately know if it's stable. Then you recompute the graph while waiting for your next user input. The user experience is smoother, and unless somebody is clicking *very* fast, they shouldn't ever notice a slowdown.

You can find **all** a graph's cut vertices in O(n) time with a DFS.

From Wikipedia on [biconnected components](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Articulation_vertex):

> The idea is to run a depth-first search while maintaining the following information:
>
> - the depth of each vertex in the depth-first-search tree (once it gets visited)
> - for each vertex v, the lowest depth of neighbors of all descendants of v in the depth-first-search tree, called the lowpoint.
>
> The lowpoint of v can be computed after visiting all descendants of v ... as the minimum of :
>
> - the depth of v
> - the depth of all neighbors of v (beside the parent of v in the depth-first-search tree)
> - the lowpoint of all children of v in the depth-first-search tree.
>
> *The key fact is that a nonroot vertex v is a cut vertex (or articulation point) separating two biconnected components if and only if there is a child **`y`** of **`v`** such that `lowpoint(y) ≥ depth(v)`.*
>
> The root vertex must be handled separately: it is a cut vertex if and only if it has at least two children.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider the so-called [`Flood-fill`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) algorithm, to label nodes and see if the memberships are the same.

Here's a simple graph. We have the original graph G, and then we remove one cube each to get the graphs H and I.

[image]

The [`igraph`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/igraph/index.html) package is great to test for graph connectedness. In the test example above, G and H are okay, but removing edge (3,5) causes the membership of 5, 6,7 to be different from that of node 1, the "earth node." (So in the 3rd graph, Graph I, you should remove cubes 5,6,and 7.)

**In R language, using the igraph library**

```
library(igraph)
edges <- c(c(1,2), c(2,3), c(2,4), c(3,5), c(5,6), c(5,7), c(6,7))
g<- graph(edges, directed=FALSE)
clusters(g)$membership  # 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

edges <- c(c(1,2), c(2,3), c(2,4), c(3,5), c(5,6), c(5,7)) # drop edge(6,7)
h<- graph(edges, directed=FALSE)
clusters(h)$membership # 1 1 1 1 1 1 1


edges <- c(c(1,2), c(2,3), c(2,4), c(5,6), c(5,7), c(6,7)) # drop (3,5)
i<- graph(edges, directed=FALSE)
clusters(i)$membership # 1 1 1 1 2 2 2
```

`clusters` is a function that comes with the igraph package. And its `membership` value shows the labels of each node in the graph. If any node (cube in your case) has a different membership value than that of the "earth node" then it is not connected to the ground, and should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution is to use BFS (Breadth-First Search) to check whether all immediate neighbors of the removed node (minecraft block) belong to the same connected component.

The first neighbor is labeled and then all others are checked wheter they connect to some labeled node.

Here is my tested code (C#):

```
public bool CanRemoveNode(int indexNode)
{
    var initialNeighbors = this.nodeNeighbors[indexNode];

    if (initialNeighbors.Count() < 2)
    {
        // leaf node - can be safely removed
        return true;
    }

    HashSet<int> nodesComponent = new HashSet<int>(initialNeighbors.Take(1));
    HashSet<int> nodesProcessed = new HashSet<int>();
    Queue<int> nodesVisit = new Queue<int>();

    foreach (int indexNodeStart in initialNeighbors.Skip(1))
    {
        nodesProcessed.Clear();

        nodesVisit.Clear();
        nodesVisit.Enqueue(indexNodeStart);

        while (nodesVisit.Any())
        {
            int indexNodeCurrent = nodesVisit.Dequeue();

            nodesProcessed.Add(indexNodeCurrent);
            nodesComponent.Add(indexNodeCurrent);

            foreach (int indexNodeNeighbor in this.nodeNeighbors[indexNodeCurrent])
            {
                    if (indexNodeNeighbor == indexNode)
                    {
                        // do not inspect removed node
                        continue;
                    }

                    if (nodesProcessed.Contains(indexNodeNeighbor))
                    {
                        // neighbor node already processed
                        continue;
                    }

                    if (nodesComponent.Contains(indexNodeNeighbor))
                    {
                        // neighbor node belongs to the component - we can terminate search
                        goto NextStartNode;
                    }

                    // mark neighbor node for further inspection
                    nodesVisit.Enqueue(indexNodeNeighbor);
            }
        }

        return false;

        NextStartNode:
        ;
    }

    return true;
}
```

The 'nodeNeighbors' dictionary contains neighbor indices for each node.

In the worst case scenario, we need to run as many BFS iterations as the length of the longest path between any two immediate neighbor nodes.

A faster method would be to label each immediate neighbor with unique numeric label and then perform Connected Component Labeling. We can run parallel BFS search for each label and terminate whenever two labels meet and we perform Union operation on the underlying Union-Find structure.

The whole search can terminate when there are as many Union operations performed as there are initial labels minus one, i.e. all labels belong to same component.

Another speed improvement would be to create multiple "seeds" uniformly distributed around the point of removal. Each seed is a node with unique label. This guarantees that the components will be connected sooner into one.

You can also terminate search after some number of iterations (e.g. 10 000) since that means the cubes are connected at to a very large distance and the player won't even find there is a disconnection.

The search can be also performed on background after this point.

Answer (score 0):

Check below code, graphA is broken and graphB is not, the isGraphBroken method checks that for you and even tell you how much is callstack and also and which nodes are broken from others:

```js
let graphA = [
  ['A', 'B'],
  ['C', 'D'],
  ['D', 'E']
];

let graphB = [
  ['A', 'B'],
  ['B', 'C'],
  ['C', 'D'],
  ['D', 'E']
];
        
function isGraphBroken(graph) {
    let map = new Map();
    let allNodes = new Set();
    let callStack = 0;

    graph.forEach(([x, y]) => {
        allNodes.add(x);
        allNodes.add(y);
        callStack++;
        if (map.has(x)) {
            map.get(x).add(y);
        } else {
            map.set(x, new Set([y]));
        }

        if (map.has(y)) {
            map.get(y).add(x);
        } else {
            map.set(y, new Set([x]));
        }
    });

    if (allNodes.size <= 1) {
        console.log("there is a way between each node pairs");
        return false;
    } 
    
    let traverseNode = (node => {
        callStack++;
        if (allNodes.size == 0) {
            return;
        }

        if (allNodes.has(node))
            allNodes.delete(node);

        if (allNodes.size == 0) {
            return;
        }

        let childs = map.get(node);
        if (childs && childs.size > 0)
            childs.forEach(child => {
                if (allNodes.has(child)) {
                    traverseNode(child);
                }
            });
    });

    traverseNode(allNodes.values().next().value);

     console.log("callstack length", callStack);
    if (allNodes.size == 0) {
        console.log("there is a way between each node pairs");
        return false;
    }
    console.log("no way from these nodes to others:", ...allNodes);
    return true;

}

console.log("checking ... graphA:")
isGraphBroken(graphA);
console.log("checking ... graphB:")
isGraphBroken(graphB);
```